# Change gradient for UIButton for different states

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, cagradientlayer

Recently I've encountered a problem. I have a UIButton and 2 images for it. 1 for normal state and 1 for highlighted. The problem is that normal state image is transparent and I should use gradient to fill it. But if I do it, my highlighted image never appears. Here's the part of the code:

```
    UIImage *balloonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"balloon.png"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(3, 3, 3, 3)];
    UIImage *balloonImageDown = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"balloon-down.png"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(3, 3, 3, 3)];

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320 - 45 - 10, 100);
    gradient.cornerRadius = 3.0f;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:221.0f/255.0f green:231.0f/255.0f blue:246.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:191.0f/255.0f green:207.0f/255.0f blue:234.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor], nil];
    self.balloonButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.balloonButton.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
    [self.balloonButton setBackgroundImage:balloonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.balloonButton setBackgroundImage:balloonImageDown forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    self.theImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc]init]autorelease];
    [self.balloonButton addSubview:theImageView];
    [self.contentView addSubview:balloonButton];
```

The gradient looks as it should and everything is working. Except for changing the image if the button is tapped.

Is there a way to put balloonImageDown in front of the gradient? Or how can I do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes ! I think what you mean is to put a transparent layer ?

Comment: Have you considered changing an alpha parameter of your gradient color to something lower than non-transparent? Like to 0.4 from 1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[yourButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.6 blue:0.9 alpha:0.5]
//                                set 'alpha' to something less than 1. -----^^^
```

This is what you do to make it transparent.(changing the alpha value)
You should be changing these values in touchdown and touch up method.